# Trying setOnQueryTextListener in searchView

Tags: android, searchview

I want to create a `searchview` that when the user typing , a table will be created.
From a little search I understood I need to use this method : setOnQueryTextListener.
I get an error in this line :

search.**`setOnQueryTextListener**(new OnQueryTextListener() {`

with the message:

The method `setOnQueryTextListener(SearchView.OnQueryTextListener)` in the type SearchView is not applicable for the arguments (`new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){}`).
Thanks !

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.restTable);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_data,menu);
    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    search.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String namelike) {
            if(namelike.length()>0)
            {
                dataHandler.getRestLike(namelike);
                createTableLayout(table);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

    });

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can't see the error. Try implementing SearchView.OnQueryTextListener interface in your activity and setting search.setOnQueryTextListener(this)

Comment: Try to impliment this library https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete